# CloudFoundry and redirect in Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, ping, cloud-foundry

A simple Sinatra app in CloudFoundry seems to give problems:

```
get '/ping' do
  "OK"
end

get '/ping_redirect' do
  redirect '/ping'
end
```

The `ping` works, the `ping_redirect` does not and gives an error:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   nginx

Any idea how to solve it?

If you'd like to test it, see [here](http://sc_app.cloudfoundry.com/ping) and [here](http://sc_app.cloudfoundry.com/ping_redirect).

I need a solution for redirects in Sinatra.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to push the following to ghoping.cloudfoundry.com:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/ping' do
    "OK"
end

get '/ping_redirect' do
    redirect '/ping'
end
```

The redirect is working fine for me: http://ghoping.cloudfoundry.com/ping_redirect

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to mixing a faulty reverse proxy config and a version of Sintra >= 1.2.

From the [1.2 release notes](http://www.sinatrarb.com/2011/03/03/sinatra-1.2.0.html):

> ### Configurable redirects
>
> In 1.1 we made sure all redirects were absolute URIs, to conform with RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1). This will result in issues for you if you have a broken Reverse Proxy configuration. If so, you should really fix your configuration. If you are unable to do so, a simple disable :absolute_redirects will now give you back the 1.0 behavior.

I applied this knowledge to your example to get the following working code (except I like pongs with my pings):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

disable :absolute_redirects

get '/pong' do
    "pong!"
end

get '/ping' do
    redirect '/pong'
end
```

Comment: How do I otherwise fix the config? I suppose my problem is similar. I have docker containers for nginx and for sinatra and once I do `redirect '/'` it pushes the container name into the browser url while it's internal, and I need to preserve the IP (or a hostname if I attach the domain). My nginx config is: `server {
  listen 8002;
  server_name ...ip...;
  location / {

    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    set $upstream http://...name...:8001;
    proxy_pass $upstream;

  }
}
`